# Spring cloud Netflix Eureka calls are in CLOSE_WAIT State

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

We are using the following technologies,

- Moneta boot version: 2.6.17
- Spring.cloud.version: 2021.0.6
- Jdk : 17
- Spring cloud Netflix Eureka server

The problem is that TCP Eureka connections are stuck in CLOSE_WAIT State. Could you please provide the solution for closing these connections.

More information for this issue:

Eureha Server port is 8761

```
[xyz@xxxxx0011111 ~]$ netstat -ant |grep CLOSE_WAIT

tcp 1 0 127.0.0.1:40234 127.0.0.1:8761 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp 1 0 127.0.0.1:33584 127.0.0.1:8761 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp 1 0 127.0.0.1:55796 127.0.0.1:43819 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp 1 0 127.0.0.1:37506 127.0.0.1:8761 CLOSE_WAIT
```